# how to fix undefined property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, prototype, undefined

i have this script:

```
var Tord = (function () {

    Tord.prototype.getHeader = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

    return Tord;
})();

$(document).ready(function() {

    var tod = new Tord();
    tod.getHeader();
});
```

i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` line 3

i don't understand why?

here is how my js files are loaded:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/style.css" />
    <script src="public/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="public/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="public/script.js"></script>
```

`script.js` has the script from above.

any ideas?  thanks.

Comment: Tord should not be self invoking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of exactly the code you've shown. Look, when this line is invoked...

```
Tord.prototype.getHeader = function () {
```

... Tord *is* undefined. But Tord should be a function when you set this (as `prototype` should be a property of constructor function to be of any use) - and you don't make any efforts to make Tord a function at all.

I think what you want to do *may* be achieved with this:

```
var Tord = (function () {
    var Tord = function() {}; // to properly name the constructor
    Tord.prototype.getHeader = function () {
        alert('test');
    };
    return Tord;
})();
```

With this you can define different constructors based on some external logic (but still define them once). But in the current state of your code there's no need to make it that complex: this...

```
var Tord = function() {};
Tord.prototype.getHeader = function() { ... };
```

... should suffice, in my opinion.

Comment: i was thinking this is a well used pattern in javascript in order to use `var tod = new Tord();`

Comment: got it now. i needed a constructor where i define Tord :) lots of thanks

Comment: The easiest solution is to just turn the anonymous IIFE into a function declaration. The rest can stay as it is.